# GitLab graphql get updatedAt in millisecond precision

Tags: graphql, gitlab

```
query {
  project ( fullPath: “<project_name>”) {
    issues ( types: [ISSUE] after:“”) {
      count nodes {
        title
        updatedAt
        id
        iid
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the GitLab GraphQL api to fetch issues from a  project returns `updatedAt` of an issue in seconds precision `(“updatedAt”: “2023-05-16T19:46:12Z”)`

The GitLab Rest api returns `“updated_at”:“2023-05-02T23:41:22.316Z”` including milliseconds.

Is there a way to have the GitLab GraphQL query return time in millisecond precision?